# Spring Ehcache MBean Monitoring

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, mbeans

I am using Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE and EHcache 2.8.1. on JBoss 7.1.1

With the following configuration in `applicationContext.xml` my caching is working good.

```
<cache:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
   <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Now I want to add the monitoring capabilities with MBean. I changed the configuration in `applicationContext.xml` as follows – added 2 new beans “managementService” and “mbeanServer”, no other change.
This is the current configuration.

```
<cache:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="managementService"
        class="net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService"
        init-method="init"
        destroy-method="dispose">

        <constructor-arg ref="cacheManager"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="mbeanServer"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg index="4" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg index="5" value="true"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
   <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>    

<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

With this configuration I get the following error on application server start up.

```
14:05:32,208 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: **Error creating bean with name 'managementService'** defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' to required type 'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]**: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'managementService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' to required type 'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: Try removing you mbean stuff, and replace it with `<context:mbean-export/>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the `ehcache` bean to the constructor of the `managementService` bean not `cacheManager`. If you look at the definition of `cacheManager` the `ehcache` bean is passed as `cacheManager`. The factory bean will provide an instance of `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager`.